# Log all response cookies in Postman

Tags: cookies, postman

I know I'm able to log a single response cookie using Postman, but is it possible to log ALL the response cookies in one go?

I'm trying to troubleshoot a test and would like to know what cookies are coming back, and I can't seem to get this solution to work:

```
const jar = pm.cookies.jar();

jar.clear(env, function (error) {
    jar.getAll(env, function (error, cookies) {
       console.log("cookies: " + cookies);
    });
});
```

In the console "cookies" just remains undefined, and that's after adding the above code to the 'Tests' tab...

Thanks.

Comment: Have you whitelisted the domain? Also its wrapped in a clear, would that get rid of them?You could also try ` pm.cookies.toObject()`.

Comment: @DannyDainton actually, not sure why that clear is there, but I have tried it without the clear and the result is the same. As for whitelisting, 'env' in the above example was set to the service's domain but, following that lead, I replaced it with the full service URL and now I seem to be getting hits! Thank you.  :bow

Comment: Awesome! Might be worth adding the solution for other people and closing out the question. 

Comment: @DannyDainton definitely, will do. Got another one coming, so need this off the list!

Answer (score 0):

I resolved this issue by replacing the following line

`const env = "integration-api.yyyy.xxx.xxxx.net";`

with the full endpoint URL:

`const env = "integration-api.yyyy.xxx.xxxx.net/api/v1/etc/etc";`

Full code now looks like this:

```
const env = "integration-api.yyyy.xxx.xxxx.net/api/v1/etc/etc";
const jar = pm.cookies.jar();

    jar.getAll(env, function (error, cookies) {
       console.log("cookies: " + cookies);
    });
```

Thanks to @DannyDainton for the pointers.